# Por que uma Stored Procedure gera resultados diferentes se executados no Workbench e no Java com JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, stored-procedures

Tenho uma Stored Procedure no MySQL que está funcionando normalmente quando executo a partir do Workbench, porém ao executar esse mesmo procedimento no Java/JBDC estou obtendo valores errados e diferentes dos obtidos no Workbench.

Minha Stored Procedure faz a contagem vários registros de outras tabelas e consolida todos os resultados na tabela destino. A parte do meu procedimento que está apresentando divergência segue abaixo:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `processa_iap`(IN data_movimento DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE dia_mov INT;
    DECLARE mes_mov INT;
    DECLARE ano_mov INT;

    SET dia_mov = DAY(data_movimento); 
    SET mes_mov = MONTH(data_movimento);
    SET ano_mov = YEAR(data_movimento); 

    INSERT INTO IAP_ATINGIDO(MES,ANO,PA,DEB)
    SELECT mes_mov 'MES', ano_mov 'ANO', A.CODPAC, COUNT(A.CODPAC)
        FROM ASSOCIADOS A, (SELECT DISTINCT CC.COD_ASSOC
            FROM CONTAS_CARTAO CC
            WHERE CC.ESTADO_CARTAO='Operativo' AND CC.COD_ASSOC IS NOT NULL 
            AND CC.TITULARIDADE='TITULAR' 
            AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%Poupança%' 
            AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%Salário%' 
            AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%BNDES%') C
        WHERE A.COD=C.COD_ASSOC
        GROUP BY A.CODPAC
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DEB=VALUES(DEB);
END
```

Código do método Java onde executo a Stored Procedure:

```
public void processaIAP() throws SQLException {
    try {
        sql = "{CALL processa_iap(?)}";
        CallableStatement cstm = connection.prepareCall(sql);

        Date data = buscaMenorDataImportacoes();
        cstm.setDate(1, data);

        cstm.execute();
        cstm.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Notei que a diferença apresentada nos resultados entre as duas execuções corresponde com a ausência dos NOT LIKE na cláusula WHERE da subconsulta presente na Stored Procedure, ou seja, é como se quando eu executasse o procedimento no Java ele desconsiderasse as seguintes instruções SQL:

```
AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%Poupança%' 
AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%Salário%' 
AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%BNDES%'
```

Tentei utilizando várias versões do conector MySQL para Java mas o problema persiste. Alguém já se deparou com problema parecido? Alguma solução?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei o porquê, e se alguém tiver alguma ideia favor contribuir conosco, mas o problema estava na utilização em conjunto do comando de negação NOT e a utilização de algum caractere especial nas strings da consulta. Só descobri através de tentativa e erro. A solução para o meu problema foi a seguinte:

```
AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%Poupan_a%' 
AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%Sal_rio%' 
AND CC.PRODUTO NOT LIKE '%BNDES%'
```